# Every morning the computer is frozen

Tags: windows-10, freeze, hibernate

My windows 10 desktop computer has the "Power options" configured as in the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

I assume those mean that it should never suspend.

However, since my last (automatic) update (some days ago, so everything should be up to date), every morning I need to hard reset my PC since it is frozen. I never turn off the computer.

I don't understand if it is frozen, hibernated, suspended, or whatever other possible state. The lights are on, but nothing happens when I type on my keyboard or move the mouse.

I have searched the internet looking for a solution, I even tried to contact gods and understand the issue, but I am still in the deepest, total darkness.

The logs do not provide any cue. Some days it seems the computer is on and doing background stuff when I get to work, sometimes it seems idle. There are no particular error or suspicious messages that provide a hint about the reason of the complete lock.

Is there anyone who can help me or provide a link to some resources?

Comment: Take a look at the system event logs for clues

Comment: I forgot to mention: I have inspected the log but could not find anything relevant. I am modifying the question.

Comment: You disabled suspension but the computer is still configured to go to sleep.  "allow hybrid sleep: on"